# Getting Error: Error: Cannot find module 'src/core/configurations/configFunctions when executing "protractor ./conf.ts --suite homepage"

Tags: typescript, protractor

Anyone please help me with following issue. I have an ***ConfigFunctions*** class as following
[image: I have an ***ConfigFunctions*** class as following]

Then I try to access ***loadConfig*** function of this class in my spec verify.home.page.display.correclt.spec.ts
[image: I try to access ***loadConfig*** function of this class in my spec verify.home.page.display.correclt.spec.ts]

Unfortunately, I got following error when trying to execute my test script
[image: Unfortunately, I got following error when trying to execute my test script]

Comment: Update github link
https://github.com/nhantrantrong/protractor-e2e-project

Comment: can you try to import from './configurations/configfunctions'

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have tried already, but the issue was not solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path you have written in import is incorrect, try to prove relative url with root like '../../../configurations/configFunctions'

Comment: Many thanks for your help, unfortunately, the issue was not solved. The error still occurs in class

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue following these steps:

1. Change path location in import sentence to relative as below
   [image]
2. Due to I am using `tsc` command to compile ts scripts files to js script file, so I need to add `rm -rf dist` command to delete my dist folder before compile test script file again

[image]

3. Finally, my issue was solved
   Many thanks for you're great effort :)